# DD4T 2.0 Issue - Could not find view model for item with Publication ID 'DD4T.ContentModel.ComponentPresentation'

Tags: dd4t

I'm using the [Sample DD4T 2.0 Application](https://bitbucket.org/trivident/simple-dd4t2-app/src) from Katerina and updated the references to DD4T 2.2. Running the sample app I get the following error:

> Could not find view model for item with Publication ID 'DD4T.ContentModel.ComponentPresentation'

Do I need to update some of the code to work with 2.2 or update the config?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error means that the ViewModelFactory is unable to find a suitable ViewModel for your component presentation. The most common causes for this are:

- The root element name does not match the first parameter in the ContentModel attribute (it's case-sensitive)
- The second parameter in the ContentModel attribute is set to false (you can set it to false for classes representing embedded schemas or linked schemas, but you must set it to false for component presentations)
- The ViewModel class does not implement IViewModel

Also note that the root element names for your schemas should be unique, otherwise DD4T will never be able to find a matching ViewModel.